# Is there a sample code for using IBM Bluemix Container API?

Tags: api, containers, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to create container in bluemix with API as it in http://ccsapi-doc.mybluemix.net   In the document it mentions:

*When using the API with the new model, the following HTTP headers shall be provided:
X-Auth-Token = Bluemix JWT Token
X-Auth-Project-Id = Space GUID*

But I have no idea how to get or generate the Bluemix JWT Token. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get `X-Auth-Token` by `cf oauth-token` command. Then copy and paste rest of the part after `bearer`. And you also can get `X-Auth-Project-Id` by `cf space --guid <space Name>`. Please see below commands;

```
$ cf login -a api.<region>.bluemix.net -u <space name> -o <org name> -s <space name>

$ cf ic login

$ cf oauth-token

$ cf space <space-name> --guid (space name where the container exists)
```

Comment: For me this always results in an invalid token, even if I did `cf login` and `cf ic init` the minute before using the token. Also the information shown by `cf login` confirm that I am using the correct user and that I am using the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the Authentication section on that page and the "Get TLS Certificate" to show more info

[image]

When you enter the values and click "try it out" you will see additional output generated with token info.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative Method:

You can retrieve **X-Auth-Token** and **X-Auth-Project-Id** with this command:

```
cf login
CF_TRACE=true cf ic login
```

Copy all output in a .txt file and search for X-Auth-Token and X-Auth-Project-Id

here there is a simple example:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Auth-Token: asdlkfajdfdkaldkjfskl239049283049jsdfjksl29304" --header "X-Auth-Project-Id: sdfadf-0090-43ef-22932-23434234" "https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers/quota"


Response:
The output of API is like this:
{
  "account_type": "TRIAL",
  "country_code": "ITA",
  "org_quota": {
    "floating_ips_max": "2",
    "floating_ips_space_default": "2",
    "floating_ips_usage": 2,
    "ram_max": "2048",
    "ram_space_default": "2048",
    "ram_usage": 2048,
    "subnet_usage": -1,
    "subnets_default": "5",
    "subnets_max": 0
  },
  "space_quota": {
    "floating_ips_max": 2,
    "ram_max": 2048,
    "subnets_max": -1
  }
```